# Refreshing JSP select list value on Page refresh

Tags: java, jsp

I have below code in my jsp :

```
    <select name="productId" id ="productId" onchange="getDetail()">
    <% for (int i = 0;i < no_rows;i++){
    %>
    <option value="<%=ar[i]%>"><%=ar[i]%></option>
    <%
    }
     %>
    </select>
```

On page refresh(F5), the values in the drop down is not getting refreshed.The previously selected value remain there. DB call to fetch the detail is in JSP itself.

How to refresh the values?

Comment: not getting refreshed with what? if you send a list to the jsp the same list will appear, with what are you trying to refresh the combobox?

Comment: On Pressing F5 to refresh the whole page, my expectation is that the dropdown should be refreshed by the default value i.e. "". @Sergio Martinez

Comment: @Aalekh your `ar[i]` element will be on the first place if you refresh the page and also this doesnt mean it is selected..Put another option before loop and then refresh it will it will be shown at first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try JSTL <[c:forEach](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm)> Tag instead

```
<select name="productId" id ="productId" onchange="getDetail()">
  <c:forEach var="item" items=${yourListNameStoredInSomeScope}>
     <option value="{item}">${item}<option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
 <select name="productId" id ="productId" onchange="getDetail()">
    <option value=" " selected></option>
    <% for (int i = 0;i < no_rows;i++){
    %>
    <option value="<%=ar[i]%>"><%=ar[i]%></option>
    <%
    }
     %>
</select>
```

if you use selected attribute , when the drop down is loaded, the pre-selected option is the default in your case " ".